# Label text not updating when SEND button is pressed - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have contact us page where I am sending mail when SEND button is pressed, everything works fine but button wasnt disabled at the end of the code, and label text was not updated to reflect change. I am entirely sure what label is not updated as code executes just fine.

This is master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MIMO.master.cs" Inherits="MIMO_WEB_R02.MIMO" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <link href="WebStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<Div id ="Navbar">
    <img class="logo" src="Images/LOGO%20MIMO%20V1.png" />
            <ul class="Menu">
            <li><a href="About.aspx">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">SERVICES</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            
                <asp:LinkButton id="D1" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" Text="MAINTENANCE & PLANNING"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton class="link" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click">TESTING & VERIFICATION</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton class="link" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click">AUDITS & INSPECTION</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton class="link" runat="server">UNCERTAINTY CALCULATIONS</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton class="link" runat="server">MIS-MEASUREMENTS</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton class="link" runat="server">VBA DEVELOPMENT</asp:LinkButton>

            </div></li>
            <li><a href="Calculations.aspx">CALCULATIONS</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.aspx">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
            </Div>
            <div id ="Image-Content">
                <img Class="IGM" src="Images/TwoRig-CRP.jpg" />
                </div>
            <div id ="Link-Content">

                 <asp:HyperLink ID="L1" runat="server" Text="LINK1"></asp:HyperLink><p> to </p>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="L2" runat="server" Text="LINK2"></asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
        
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Body" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <div id ="Footer"><h5>address goes here</h5></div>
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This child page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MIMO.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="MIMO_WEB_R02.ContactUs" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="JsValidation.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 181px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Body" runat="server">

     <div class ="Page_Content">
     <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
     <p>Thanks for visiting our website for any information get in touch</p>
            
    <fieldset style="Width:40%">
        <Legend>Contact Us</legend><table id="ContactDetails">
     <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">Name</td><td class="auto-style1"><asp:TextBox ID="SenderName" Placeholder="Name" runat="server" Width="200px"/></td>
      <td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameID" ControlToValidate="SenderName" ValidationGroup="groupName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name is required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
     <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">Surname</td><td class="auto-style1"><asp:TextBox ID="SenderSurname" Placeholder="Surname" runat="server" Width="200px"/></td>
         <td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SurnameID" ControlToValidate="SenderSurname" ValidationGroup="groupName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Last Name is required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
     <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">Title</td><td class="auto-style1"><asp:TextBox ID="SenderTitle" Placeholder="Title" runat="server" Width="200px"/></td>
         <td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TitleVal" ControlToValidate="SenderTitle" ValidationGroup="groupName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Title is required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         </td></tr>
     <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">Company</td><td class="auto-style1"><asp:TextBox ID="SenderCompany" Placeholder="Company" runat="server" Width="200px"/></td>
         <td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CompanyID" ControlToValidate="SenderCompany" ValidationGroup="groupName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Company Name is required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
     <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">Email</td><td class="auto-style1"><asp:TextBox ID="SenderEmail" Placeholder="Email" runat="server" Width="200px"/></td>
         <td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailID" ControlToValidate="SenderEmail" ValidationGroup="groupName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email is required" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" Font-Size="Small">
      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
     <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">Telephone (Optional)</td><td class="auto-style1"><asp:TextBox ID="SenderTelephone" Placeholder="Telephone" runat="server" Width="200px"/></td>
         <td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TelephoneID" ControlToValidate="SenderTelephone" ValidationGroup="groupName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Telephone is required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small">
      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">Subject</td><td class="auto-style1"><asp:TextBox ID="SenderSubject" Placeholder="Subject" runat="server" Width="200px"/></td>
         <td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SubjectID" ControlToValidate="SenderSubject" ValidationGroup="groupName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Subject is required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small">
      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
     <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">Message Body</td><td class="auto-style1"><asp:TextBox ID="TxtComments" Placeholder="Email" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="MultiLineTextBox" Width="200px" Height="87px"/>
         </td><td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Comments" ControlToValidate="TxtComments" ValidationGroup="groupName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Comments are required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small">
      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td class="auto-style1"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="ClientSideClick(this);" Text="SEND" Width="78px" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
         </td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="This is some label text here"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>    
     </table>
        
      </fieldset>
     </div>
  
</asp:Content>
```

This C# server code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] ParamToPass = new String[9];
        String ConnectionString = "DESKTOP-9V04GKP";
        try
        {
        ParamToPass[0] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        ParamToPass[1] = SenderName.Text;
        ParamToPass[2] = SenderSurname.Text;
        ParamToPass[3] = SenderTitle.Text;
        ParamToPass[4] = SenderCompany.Text;
        ParamToPass[5] = SenderEmail.Text;
        ParamToPass[6] = SenderTelephone.Text;
        ParamToPass[7] = SenderSubject.Text;
        ParamToPass[8] = TxtComments.Text;

            //MailAddress to = new MailAddress("mail1");
            //MailAddress from = new MailAddress("mail2");

            //MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            //message.Subject = SenderSubject.Text.ToString();
            //message.Body = TxtComments.Text.ToString();

            //SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            //{
            //    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("credentials go here"),
            //    EnableSsl = true

            //};
            //// code in brackets above needed if authentication required


            //client.Send(message);

            Label1.Text = "Thank you for your message we will get back at you as soon as possible";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            SQL_Insert(ConnectionString, ParamToPass); 
        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "We are experiencing technical difficulty please come back at another time";
            Button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: What happens in this function is there any Response.Redirect or something that resets the function flow? SQL_Insert(ConnectionString, ParamToPass);

Comment: Can you show parts of your masterpage? Is the `ContentPlaceHolder` inside an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: @Ashoka, No that part of the code works fine, all record are inserted into SQL server, and I can see them live, everytime I press the send button. I tried adding debug.writeline at the end of the C code, so i can confirm code executed all the way to the end, and no expection was thrown.

Comment: @Homungus, I am looking for a way to upload my master page, since I dont know how to do this. But I am not using update panel anywhere on any page.

Comment: Don't need to upload your whole masterpage, just relevant parts of your markup.

Comment: @Homungus, I have added ASP Master Page to my original post

Answer (score 0):

Since all asp.net button are type "submit", then page refreshes after you click the button and generates PostBack.

You have two options to deal with that.

**Option 1 - "preventDefault()" on your button:**

```
$("#Button1").click(function (e) {    
 e.preventDefault();
}
```

You can add `e.preventDefault();` to your existing `ClientSideClick` function, which you didnt include to your question, so I cant edit your current code.

**Option 2 - Change OnClientClick from:**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="ClientSideClick(this)" Text="SEND" Width="78px" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

To:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="ClientSideClick(this); return false;" Text="SEND" Width="78px" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Comment: HI, I will try your suggestions. I have tried added is.postback if statement but that as well didnt update the label.

Comment: @Milenko Use of ``if(Page.IsPostBack)`` doesnt help you much in this case, it could, but it would be much more complicated than those 2 options. Let me know if that helped, or if you have any further questions.

Comment: I have added postback again delete all code from C# block and only left following             if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Thank you for your message we will get back at you as soon as possible";
                Button1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Postback off");
            }                                                           Now label will get updated, and send button will be disabled. I will try it again on the entire C# code block

Comment: @Tofik.It works without a postback as well, if I delete the entire C code and only change label text and disable the button - works normal, but as soon as I inlcude the entire code it wont work. Page will also never complete loading, entries however will be visible in SQL server. It just apperas code will ever reach the end.

Comment: @Milenko Setup a breakpoint at the beggining of your function and go step by step and check where code fails. Also check browser console after you try to run the code.